# Retrieving digits from multiple file names using regex

Tags: regex, bash, unix

Given files:

```
aaabbcc.43.311b.file
ddeeff.x51.311b.file
ffg.1.311b.file
hh.ii.jj.x26.311b.file
ll.m.311.311b.file
```

How would I get the numbers within the file name but not 311b? So I would like to get 43, 51, 1, 26 and 311.

Comment: Is it always `311b.file`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with grep:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+\b' test.text
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's#[^0-9]\+\([0-9]\+\).*#\1#' INPUTFILE
```

Will give you the needed output for the exampled lines. It searches the input lines for the first group of digit characters, and prints only them.

Answer (score 0):

```
% ls
aaabbcc.43.311b.file   ddeeff.x51.311b.file   ffg.1.311b.file        hh.ii.jj.x26.311b.file ll.m.311.311b.file

% ls|grep -o -P '\d+(?=\.311b\.file)'
43
51
1
26
311
```